# XML to POJO Mapping

Tags: java, xml, jibx

I have a service that does the following:

1. receives different XML requests
2. turns them into JIBX-generated Java objects
3. maps the JIBX-generated Java objects into POJOs
4. sends the POJOs to another service
5. gets a POJO response back
6. maps POJO back into JIBX-generated Java objects
7. turns JIBX-generated Java objects back into XML
8. returns XML to client.

I'd like to make this process more efficient. Can anyone suggest how? Can JIBX map directly into my POJOs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Jibx can map directly to your POJOs using Jibx mapping files. I think the below link will be very helpful to understand Jibx binding.

[Jibx Introduction](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/tutorial/binding-start.html#intro)

Answer (score 0):

In this you needed library which is available in the url(4shared.com) commented in comments.

```
 package com.xml.Sample.MainP;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;

    import com.xml.Sample.Actions.XMLAction;
    import com.xml.Sample.Model.States;

    public class Retrieve {
        public static String XMLModelName = "com.xml.Sample.Model.States";
        private static String cities = "E:\\Webeclipseworkspace\\Samples\\src\\Srates.xml";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                File f = new File(cities);
                Document doc = db.parse(f);
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                XMLAction xmla = new XMLAction();
                List<States> listXML = xmla.readData(XMLModelName, doc);
                // System.out.println(listXML);
                String xmlData = xmla.writtingData(listXML);
                System.out.println(xmlData);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

    }



    package com.xml.Sample.Model;

    import com.xml.Sample.XMLAnn.XMLColumn;
    import com.xml.Sample.XMLAnn.XMLReport;

    @XMLReport(reportName = "row")
    public class Directory {

        private String city_id;
        private String city_name;
        private String state_id;

        @XMLColumn(label = "city_id")
        public String getCity_id() {
            return city_id;
        }

        public void setCity_id(String city_id) {
            this.city_id = city_id;
        }

        @XMLColumn(label = "city_name")
        public String getCity_name() {
            return city_name;
        }

        public void setCity_name(String city_name) {
            this.city_name = city_name;
        }

        @XMLColumn(label = "state_id")
        public String getState_id() {
            return state_id;
        }

        public void setState_id(String state_id) {
            this.state_id = state_id;
        }

    }
```

Here I Created Own Library For Converting Pojo classes to xml and xml to pojo classes.

Use Below Link(4Shared.com) at Comments to download Library to add for The Above Code.

Comment: Use Above Lonk To Download Library

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Can U Please Use the link to download code may be you will get Clear View of Code.

Answer (score -1):

String(XML in String) to List

**1. FolderItem.java**

```
<code>
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FolderItem {
    long itemId ;
       String itemName; 
       String itemType;
       String description;
       String[] tags;
       String path;
/* setters and getters 
   Annotations not required*/
}
</code>
```

**2. FolderItems.java**

```
<code>
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FolderItems {
    @XmlElement
    private List<FolderItem> folderItem;
/* setter and getter */
}
</code>
```

**3. Testing--main method**

```
<code>
class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   FolderItems f = (FolderItems)strToVo(content, FolderItems.class);
   System.out.println(f);
}
static Object strToVo(String content, Class c) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(c);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        return unmarshaller.unmarshal(new InputSource(new StringReader(content)));
    }
}
</code>
```

**4. XML in String**

```
<code>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<FolderItems>
    <folderItem>
        <description>Lapse notice invoice for additional interests/additional insureds</description>
        <itemId>480004439</itemId>
        <itemName>Lapse_Invoice_AI</itemName>
        <itemType>application/x-thunderhead-ddv</itemType>
        <path>/Templates/Billing Center/Lapse_Invoice_AI</path>
        <tags></tags>
    </folderItem>
</FolderItems>
</code>
```

Comment: output: FolderItems [folderItem=[FolderItem [itemId=480004439, itemName=Lapse_Invoice_AI, itemType=application/x-thunderhead-ddv, description=Lapse notice invoice for additional interests/additional insureds, tags=[], path=/Templates/Billing Center/Lapse_Invoice_AI]]]